# ChromiumWebBrowser AddressChanged event not firing in Caliburn.Micro ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to capture the address change event in a ChromiumWebBrowser control within a Caliburn.Micro ViewModel, but I'm facing issues where the AddressChanged event isn't firing as expected. I've attempted to bind it using Caliburn's conventions but haven't had success so far.

Here's a simplified version of what I've tried:

In the XAML:

```
<wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="ChromiumWebBrowser"
                        Address="http://www.google.de"
                        cm:Message.Attach="[Event AddressChanged] = [Action FireAddressChanged($source, $eventArgs)]">
```

in the ViewModel:

```
public void FireAddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Print(e.Address);
}
```

Strange is, if I replace the

```
[Event AddressChanged]
```

with something like

```
[Event MouseDoubleClick]
```

the method get called (and it will threw an exception because of the eventargs, but this is not the problem).

Comment: You must bind the `ChromiumWebBrowser.Address` property to the view model. Don't handle view events in the view model in general.